# Deriving PDF in AutoRegressive Model

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

I hope that this is a right place and way to ask this question. I am trying to understand how to derive the probability density function of x(t) in an AR model of order K given (t-k) past observations.
I am  primarily referring to this [paper](http://reference.kfupm.edu.sa/content/u/n/a_unifying_framework_for_detecting_outli_70701.pdf) (Section 2.2) but it cites a Japanese book for this derivation. I could not find similar derivation in the other time series books(Shumway and stoffer, Pourahmadi). Can someone please provide me appropriate references or explain it.

Thanks for your time.
iinception

Comment: The link doesn't give us the full paper and so we can't look at Section 2.2. Can you give us the relevant part of the section that gives the derivation?

Comment: There has to be additional assumptions other than the AR order.  The marginal distribution for X(t) for a stationary AR model will be normalif the error term is normal.  But other distributiona for the error term can lead to different marginals.

Comment: @MichaelChernick thanks for the comment, I have updated the reference. Yes the error term is normal and I want to understand how they derived it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the notation used in the paper but they assume the error term is normal with mean 0 and constant variance.  What they derive in section 2.2 is the conditional distribution of X(t) given the previous k observations for a kth order AR process. The result is really rather simple.

The model is as follows:

X(t)= a$_1$ X(t-1) + a$_2$ X(t-2)+...+ a$_k$ X(t-k) + e$_t$

where e$_(t)$ is normal mean 0 and variance σ$^2$.  In this formulation the AR coefficients are given and the time series points X(t-j) for j=1,2,..., k are all given.  So all the terms except e$_t$ are fixed values.  So this means that you are just adding a constant to a single normal random variable.

So the conditional distribution of X(t) given 
X(t-1)=x(t-1), X(t-2)=x(t-2), ..., X(t-k)=x(t-k)
is normal with mean a$_1$ x(t-1) + a$_2$ x(t-2)+...+ a$_k$ x(t-k) and variance σ$^2$.

Comment: now i can understand it...thanks for the explanation @Michael Chernick ...:)